# SKAudioNode is THROWING and it never did before updating Xcode 13.4

Tags: skaudionode

I coded a fully operational video slot machine that ran perfectly prior to updating recently to Xcode 13.4. Now, SKAudioNode is causing trouble. It used to work without problems, but now, the first use of SKAudioNode anywhere in my code gives a "throwing -10878" error. The sound still plays and the app doesn't close, but every once in a while everything temporarily slows to a crawl as if the game interrupts are overloaded (which never happened before now).
I've traced the problem down to the addChild line. Keep in mind, this always worked before now.

```
            myMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "myMusicFile")
            myMusic.autoplayLooped = true
            addChild(myMusic).  <--- THROWS HERE
```

Comment: I should also add that the THROWING error repeats 8 times on first use of SKAudioNode. Then, I never see the error message again, even though my app slows down intermittently.

Comment: UPDATE: I solved the throwing problem, but every now and again, my code slows to a crawl for a moment then corrects itself and plays full speed again. Still seems to be audio related